# Is there any more information about the golden fleet?

Tags: warhammer-40k

Having read the Tallarn book one aspect really confused me.

At one point a fleet named the golden fleet, arrives led by a rogue trader named Sangrea mistress of the Eagle Claw. The fleet is stated as being made up of mercenaries with 300 ultramarine warriors also on board.

The fleet is only discussed in a couple of paragraphs. It flies into Tallarns system telling the iron warriors it is on there side, then destroys the iron warrior ships nearby before heading towards the planet. Where, it destroys everything imperial and traitor in the atmosphere trying to support the ground forces. Then the fleet leaves the system.

This seemed a random and almost pointless addition to the story and almost like it was lazy writing designed to create a way the loyalists can gain the upper hand.

Has this Golden fleet ever been mentioned or talked about before in books, source material, rules etc? Or is this the first time they have ever appeared? Is there any explanation given for there random act at Tallarn where they seem to decide not to pick a side?

Comment: It sounds like you are likely right about them. The only instance I can find of a background for them is on the German side of Lexicanum. It tells how Sangrea left with her fleet and came back to save the day like the Legion of the Damned... but all that appears to have come from the book you read. They are likely a one off thing... Google Translate may be your friend if you follow this link: http://wh40k-de.lexicanum.com/wiki/Golden_Fleet